# Why is passcode required to enable Face ID after just one failed attempt sometimes?

Tags: iphone, ios, face-id

I'm on iOS 15 and use Face ID to unlock my phone, however, sometimes I forgot that I was wearing a mask and Face ID unlock failed - most of the times I could swipe up to try it again, but sometimes passcode is required to enable Face ID after just one failed attempt. Why?

Comment: I imagine it follows similar rules to Touch ID - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223765/ios-your-passcode-is-required-to-enable-touch-id?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

An Apple support document https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208114 includes

> These are the top most reasons for iPhone to ask for passcode instead of Face ID:
>
> - You're wearing a face mask.
> - The device has just been turned on or restarted.
> - The device hasn’t been unlocked for more than 48 hours.
> - The passcode hasn’t been used to unlock the device in the last six and a half days
> - Face ID hasn't unlocked the device in the last 4 hours.
> - The device has received a remote lock command.
> - After five unsuccessful attempts to match a face.
> - After initiating power off/Emergency SOS by pressing and holding either volume button and the side buttons simultaneously for 2 seconds.

I found these on Apple support website so they might be true

Comment: Thank you for answering, I read the support article but I don't think it covers my case.

Comment: Please don't copy text without crediting where it comes from - That is plagarism